# Help integrating the transition probability of the Brownian Motion density function.

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

**1. Problem**:

Given the Brownian Motion with Drift:
$$ dx = \mu \, dt+\sigma \, dW $$
It can be shown that the transition density function is the following:
$$ p(x, t) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu t)^2}{2t\sigma^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sqrt{t\sigma^2}}$$

Therefore, If I want to find the cumulative probability for some range:

Example:
$$ \mu=0.05, \sigma=0.5$$
$$ Pr(T \leq 10, \ -\infty \leq X \leq 5) = 
\int_0^{10}\int_{-\infty}^5 \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu t)^2}{2t\sigma^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sqrt{t\sigma^2}}\,dx\,dt = 9.997 $$

- I get values that are greater than 1; therefore, I am definitely wrong. This is not a probability.

So, I have some questions:

1. What is the value that I am getting?
2. How do I read $ Pr(T \leq t, \ X \leq x) $?

Simulated Paths for the Diffusion (Equation 1, above):
[image]

Contour Plot of the Transition Probability Function:
[image]

What basic probability questions can be answered by inferring from the transition probability density?

**2. Follow up question**:

What if there was a threshold where the paths of the diffusion are being killed - doesn't the time become a random variable? i.e. A book I am reading provides the following  formula for **the probability of trajectories that are killed**:

$$
Pr(T < t \mid y) = \int_{0}^{\infty }\int_{\Omega }k(x)p(t, x\mid y)\,dx\,dt \\
$$

Example:

$$ k(x)=\lambda x^2, \ where \ \lambda=0.001 \\$$

Diffusion paths crossing the killing function $ k(x) $ (Red line)
[image]

[image]

This is where my confusion about having a random variable $ T $ comes from.

So how can I relate this conclusion with the information below about the transition probability density and the double integral on time?

**3. Lessons Learned** (Needs Verification)

Given the Brownian Motion with Drift:

$$ dx = \mu dt+\sigma dW \\ $$

**i.** ***Diffusion without Killing***:

The Transition Probability Function defined as:
$$ p(x,t)dx=P(x(t)\in(x,x+dx)) \\ $$ 
... is obtained by solving the Forward Kolmogorov PDE:
$$ \frac{\partial p(t, x)}{\partial t} = -\frac{\partial\mu p(x, t)}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^{2}\sigma p(x, t)}{\partial x^{2}} \\
p(x, 0) = \delta (x-x_{0}) \\ $$

... Inference:
$$ Pr(X \leq x) = \int_{-\infty }^{x}p(x, t)\,dx \\ $$

**ii.** ***Diffusion with Killing***:

The Transition Probability Function defined as:
$$ p(x,t)dx=P(x(t)\in(x,x+dx),T>t) $$

... is obtained by solving the Backward Kolmogorov PDE:
$$ \frac{\partial p(x, t)}{\partial t} = -k(x)p(x, t) + \frac{\partial\mu p(x, t)}{\partial x}
+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^{2}\sigma p(x, t)}{\partial x^{2}} \\
p(x, 0) = \delta (x-x_{0}) $$
$$and \ BCs $$
... Inference:
$$ Pr(T \leq t, X \leq x) =
\int_{0}^{t}\int_{-\infty }^{x}k(x)p(t, x)\,dx\,dt $$

Comment: "the cumulative probability for some range" Ambiguous expression, please explain what you mean. "$ Pr(T \leq 10, \ -\infty \leq X \leq 5)$" ?? $T$ and $X$ are not even defined, please explain what you mean. The integral you are computing is $E(L)$, where $$L=\int_0^{10}\mathbf 1_{X_t<5}dt$$ is the time spent by the process $(X_t)$ below $5$ between times $0$ and $10$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! $ T $ is the temporal random variable - $ X $ is the spatial random variable often noted as $ B(t) $. So how do I answer basic probability questions given the transition probability function?

Comment: @Did Clarification: I was treating $ p(x,t) $ like a bi-normal pdf - but I have learned that $ p(x,t) $ it is not normalized on $ t $, only on $ x $.

Comment: Its not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: @avid19 How do I calculate some cumulative probabilities - just like we would do with a single Normal Distribution ... $ Pr(X<=x) $, $ \Pr(X=x) $, $ \Pr(X>=x) $ ... except how do I use the transition probability $ p(t,x) $ since it is dependent on two variables $ x $, and $ t $?

Comment: Of course $p$ depends on $t$, that's because $X$ depends on $t$ so your probabilities depend on $t$

Comment: What is your question in the end? The formula in my first comment yields $$E(L)=\int_0^{10}\int_{-\infty}^5p_t(x)dxdt,$$ and, obviously, $E(L)$ is not constrained to be $\leqslant1$, only $$E(L)\leqslant\int_0^{10}\int_{-\infty}^\infty p_t(x)dxdt=\int_0^{10}1\cdot dt=10.$$

Comment: @Did First and foremost - thank you so much for the reply. By $ E( ) $, do you mean Expected Value? Can you please take a look at the additional evidence I added above. Is the new formula in agreement with the one you provided?

Comment: @avid19 Thank you as well for your answer. Definitely clarified a lot of details for me. Nevertheless, I would like to point you as well to the new example I added above. It seems like inferring only on $ X_t $ it is not enough to answer question when we have a diffusion with threshold. (I know, I am just mentioning this). This is where my confusion about the random variable $ T $ was springing.

Comment: Yes E stands for expectation. Re your edit, please indicate your source for the formula with $P(T<t\mid y)$ (at present the RHS does not depend on $t$).

Comment: @Did (http://www.biologie.ens.fr/bcsmcbs/IMG/pdf/Time-scalediffJPA.pdf) - Look on Page 24, Equation 4.11. Note that I have their book and the description for the equation has changed and it is the one I wrote above.

Comment: You misread: the LHS is $P(T<\tau)$ where $T$ and $\tau$ are both random (killing time and time of absorption by the boundary, respectively), as explained on page 23.

Comment: @Did But it is still referred to as a probability and above we said the double integral is an expectation. Also, in school I only learned this notation $ Pr(<R.V.>  \ <= or > \ <Fixed \ Value>) $ ...

Comment: First the easy part: $P(T<\tau)$ is also $P((T-\tau)<0)$ hence this fits the notations you learned (but I should mention this is the first time I meet somebody to whom $P(X<Y)$ with $X$ and $Y$ random variables, is a problem). Now the real beef: you misled everybody by mentioning the Brownian density $p(x,t)$ at the beginning of your post since the paper you take this from, define $$p(x,t)dx=P(x(t)\in(x,x+dx),T>t,\tau>t),$$ while the PDF you wrote is $$\gamma(x,t)dx=P(x(t)\in(x,x+dx)).$$ To see the difference, note that, for every $t$, $$\int_\Omega\gamma(x,t)dx=1$$ while ...

Comment: ... the definition of $p$ yields $$\int_\Omega p(x,t)dx=P(T>t,\tau>t)\to0,$$ when $t\to\infty$. With this definition, and with the fact that $k(\ )$ denotes the killing rate of the process, that is, the rate at which $T$ happens, one can show that indeed, $$\int_0^\infty\int_\Omega k(x)p(x,t)dxdt=P(T<\tau).$$ The case when $k(\ )$ is constant (then $T$ is simply an exponential random variable independent of everything else) can be completely written down.

Comment: @Did I have taken careful notes of every comment in this thread. Also, I added another section above 3.Lessons Learned. Last favor, can you please verify that what I gathered is correct - for completeness? PS: I am  assuming $ \tau $ goes to Infinity. Sincerely, thank you so much!

Comment: It seems you really got nothing from what I explained in painful details: "assuming that $\tau$ goes to infinity" can have no meaning whatsoever since $\tau$ is a random variable, not a real number, hence one cannot make it "go to infinity". My overall impression when rereading the exchanges above is that you wish to stick to your previous interpretation at all cost and although it has been proven wrong. Why ask a question on this site then?

Comment: @Did That is absolutely not the case. I think my lack of understanding came across as stubbornness. I did not realize until you pointed it out that tau was another RV. And that is a different problem than the one I intended to ask in my head. I am really sorry but I learned a lot from what you wrote.

Comment: OK. Perfect then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you write doesn't make sense and I think you have a lot of misunderstandings.  Your double integral makes no sense, I don't know where you got that. You don't define $T$ or $X$. I have no idea where you get the idea of "temporal" or "spatial" random variable. Let me try to clear things up for you.

$X_t$ is a collection of random variables. Each $t$ represents a single random variable.  $t$ is a *parameter*. The probability density function is as you say, $p(x, t) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu t)^{2}}{2t\sigma ^{2}}}}{\sqrt{2\pi }\sqrt{t\sigma ^{2}}}$. However this doesn't mean what you think it means. $t$ just indexes a collection of random variables. There is no such thing as the "temporal part" or "spatial part". This is NOT a bivariate density function. $t$ is a parameter just like $\sigma$ and $\mu$.

If you want to find $P(X_t \leq x)$, then just compute:

$$P(X_t \leq x)=\int_{-\infty}^x  \frac{e^{-\frac{(y-\mu t)^{2}}{2t\sigma ^{2}}}}{\sqrt{2\pi }\sqrt{t\sigma ^{2}}} dy$$

Your outcome will depend on $t$, because $X_t$ depends on $t$.

Edit, for another example consider the Poisson random variable $X_{\lambda}$ indexed by $\lambda$. What $P(X_{\lambda}=1)$? Well, $\lambda e^{-\lambda}$. Of course this depends on $\lambda$ as $X_{\lambda}$ depends on $\lambda$.

The main difference between the Brownian motion (with drift) and this Poisson example, is typically with Poisson random variables you pick a $\lambda$ and stay with it, where with Brownian motion you care about the evolution over $t$. However $t$ is **still** just some parameter.

If you really wanted to be specific, you could write $X_{t,\mu,\sigma}$ although you don't do this because $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are fixed throughout the problem. This is why you don't see $X_{\lambda}$. That's because $\lambda$ is typically fixed.

Comment: This post answered my original question.